# How to create Map using multiple lists in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to figure out how to access particular elements from RDD `myRDD` with example entries below:

```
(600,List((600,111,7,1), (615,111,3,5))
(601,List((622,112,2,1), (615,111,3,5), (456,111,9,12))
```

I want to extract some data from Redis DB using 3-rd field from sub-lists as ID. For example, in case of `(600,List((600,111,1,1), (615,111,1,5))`, the IDs are `7` and `3`. 
In case of `(601,List((622,112,2,1), (615,111,3,5), (456,111,9,12))`, the ID's are `2`, `3` and `9`.

The problem is that I don't know how to collect values using multiple IDs. In the given code below, I use `line._2(3)`, but it's not correct, because this way I access sublists instead of the fields inside these sublists.
Should I use `flatMap` or similar?

```
  val newRDD = myRDD.mapPartitions(iter => {
    val redisPool = new Pool(new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost", 6379, 2000))
    iter.map({line => (line._1,
      redisPool.withJedisClient { client =>
        val start_date: String = Dress.up(client).hget("id:"+line._2(3),"start_date")
        val end_date: String = Dress.up(client).hget("id:"+line._2(3),"end_date")
        val additionalData = List((start_date,end_date))
        Map(("base_data", line._2), ("additional_data", additionalData))
      })
    })
  })
  newRDD.collect().foreach(println)
```

If we assume that Redis DB contains some relevant data, then the result `newRDD` could be the following:

```
(600,Map("base_data" -> List((600,111,7,1), (615,111,3,5)), "additional_data" -> List((2014,2015),(2015,2016)))
(601,Map("base_data" -> List((622,112,2,1), (615,111,3,5), (456,111,9,12)), "additional_data" -> List((2010,2015),(2011,2016),(2014,2016)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of third elements of each tuple in `line._2`, use `line._2.map(_._3)` (assuming the type of `line` is `(Int, List[(Int, Int, Int, Int)])`, like it looks from your example, and types like `Any` aren't involved). Overall, it seems like your code should look like

```
iter.map({ case (first, second) => (first,
  redisPool.withJedisClient { client =>
    val additionalData = second.map { tuple =>
      val start_date: String = Dress.up(client).hget("id:"+tuple._3,"start_date")
      val end_date: String = Dress.up(client).hget("id:"+tuple._3,"end_date")
      (start_date, end_date)
    }
    Map(("base_data", second), ("additional_data", additionalData))
  })
})
```